# Is it posssible to get element Id on which custom function was fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method that fires after page load. This method has the following string:

```
$jq('#myElement').myCustomFunction("some info", "sometext");
```

My functions take 2 parameters:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myCustomFunction: function (info, text) {

    }
});
```

Can I pass to function or get inside a function the Id of an element? For the following example, it should be `#myElement`

Comment: I would assume the information you need exists on `this`. What does `console.log(this.id)` output?

Comment: @evolutionxbox 'this.id' returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin executes under the context of the jQuery object which invoked it. As such you can use `this.prop('id')` to read the id from the element.

```js
jQuery.fn.myCustomFunction = function(info, text) {
  console.log(this.prop('id'));
}

$('#myElement').myCustomFunction("some info", "sometext");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

That assumes that you're only expecting/allowing the plugin to be called on a single element. If you're allowing it to be called on multiple (which you really should in order to follow jQuery best practice) then you'll need to loop through them all.

```js
jQuery.fn.myCustomFunction = function(info, text) {
  this.each((i, el) => console.log(el.id));
}

$('.foo').myCustomFunction("some info", "sometext");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" id="myElement"></div>
<div class="foo" id="thisElement"></div>
<div class="foo" id="thatElement"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not working as expected. 
My div only has id-attribute. By that id-attribute, I call jq function. And I want to get exactly this id inside a function.
On your answer you have foo class and working with that.

Comment: The code works fine in that case, as you can see in the example above. If it's not working for you please add your code to the question so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. All works great! I just pass the wrong Id on my local machine. Big thanks!